# Insert into Access DB using VBA trying to exclude duplicates but getting an error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm sure it's something simple, but, I keep getting an error when trying to run this.  I've create a DB and want to import some data.  I've parsed the import file, and assigned the relevant data to variables.

Next step is to insert into the DB, which I've managed, but, I'd like it to ignore the row if it finds a duplicate.

The bit of code is:-

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PubHol " & "(HolidayDate, HolidayName)" & " VALUES (""" & dtOutDT & """, """ & strOutDesc & """ )" & " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PubHol as ph WHERE ph.HolidayDate = CDate ('" & dtOutDT & "'))"
MsgBox strSQL
dbCurr.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

The MsgBox shows the following output:-

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Access
---------------------------
INSERT INTO PubHol (HolidayDate, HolidayName) VALUES ("01/01/2018", "New Year's Day" ) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PubHol as ph WHERE ph.HolidayDate = CDate ('01/01/2018'))
```

All of which seems to be a valid SQL statement to me, but I get a VB Error

> Run-time error '3067' Query input must contain at least one table or
>   query.

Can anyone shed any light on where I'm going wrong?

Or any other tips on avoiding duplicates getting added to my DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` syntax together with a `WHERE` clause. (I would guess this is because `WHERE` is designed to limit the records being inserted, which only makes sense if you're trying to insert multiple records; `VALUES` in Access SQL inserts a single record.)

Ideally, you should apply a constraint and handle the resulting error, as in [Parfait's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324416/111794).

If you can't do this, (because the constraint only applies to the import and not the regular business data, or for some other reason), then either make the decision whether to `INSERT` the records in VBA, not in SQL:

```
Dim recordCount As Integer
'get the number of records matching the criteria
If recordCount = 0 Then
    'INSERT records here
End If
```

Or, if you still want to do this completely in SQL, I would suggest the following:

```
INSERT INTO PubHol (HolidayDate, HolidayName)
SELECT TOP 1 "01/01/2018", "New Year's Day"
FROM dummy
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM PubHol as ph 
    WHERE ph.HolidayDate = CDate ('01/01/2018')
)
```

`dummy` is any table in your database which has at least one record.

NB. You might want to consider using SQL parameters; you could avoid having to manually construct string and date literals, and also to avoid the date conversion within the query.

Also, it seems as though you are importing a single record at a time. If you can create a linked table to your import source, it might be better instead to create an `INSERT` query which would massage the data from the linked table into the right shape for the destination table.

Comment: I've tried to select from dummy, but VB is complaining that the table is undefined?

`INSERT INTO PubHol (HolidayDate, HolidayName) SELECT TOP 1 "01/01/2018", "New Year's Day" FROM dummy  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PubHol as ph WHERE ph.HolidayDate = CDate ('01/01/2018'))`

Should I have to define dummy anywhere?

Comment: @Dan As I wrote in my edit, _`dummy` is any table in your database which has at least one record._

Comment: Apologies, misread that bit, assumed it was the same as DUAL in Oracle!  I've created a 'dummy' table and now it works exactly as I'd hoped :-)

Thankyou so much, this has been driving me crazy all week!!

Comment: My VBA is parsing through an iCal file, downloaded from the web showing upcoming public holidays in the UK.  It's finding the relevant parts that I want (start date and title) and then inserting them into my PubHol table, which will be used elsewhere.

Comment: @Dan What does the iCal format look like? Is it a plain text file? Most text files can be imported using the [Access importing / linking facilities](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-D6973101-9547-4315-A8F8-02911B549306).

Comment: I got the file from here:-
[link](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays)

The file has lots of tags ready to import into calendar, all web searches i did suggested importing it into Outlook, then exporting as .csv and then importing into Access, I wanted to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Dan Offhand I think that unfortunately Access linked tables cannot handle this format.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion above is working a treat and only importing the bits of data I need.  It parses the file looking for the different tags at the start of each line, then extracts the data when it finds a tag, one the date, one the description of the public holiday.  Also expanded it to go to the internet to retrieve the file in the first place! :-)

Comment: @Parfait now marked as answer! Apologies, can't vote it up yet as I've not got enough reputation!

Answer (score 2):

In Access SQL dialect, you cannot run `WHERE` without a data source in query. And looking specifically, you may do well with a constraint of unique values on *HolidayDate* and *HolidayName* that disallows duplicates:

```
dbCurr.Execute "ALTER TABLE [PubHol] ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_holiday" _
                 & " UNIQUE (HolidayDate, HolidayName)"
```

Then run a regular parameterized append query where any attempt to add duplicate values will return as an exception and be rolled back.

**SQL** *(save as a query object, resuable for other holidays)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [HolidayDateParam] Datetime, [HolidayNameParam] TEXT(255);
INSERT INTO PubHol (HolidayDate, HolidayName)
VALUES ([HolidayDateParam], [HolidayNameParam])
```

**VBA**

```
Dim qdef As QueryDef

...
Set qdef = dbCurr.QueryDefs("mysavedquery")

qdef![HolidayDateParam] = dtOutDT
qdef![HolidayNameParam] = strOutDesc

qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: I've got the unique constraint set on the HolidayDate field, it's parsing a list of Public Holidays in the UK.  I'll have a play with this way though and see how I get on.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Do note this is a unique constraint on **both** fields. And if you have constraint what happens on append query?

Comment: I tried this, but it came back with an error saying that entering the data would create duplicates, so it didn't add them in.  I was hoping for a query that would only try to add if no duplicate was found, rather than error on duplicate.  Apologies if my question was unclear.  Thank you for you answer though, it looks a really good way of adding data to a table, and I'll definitely use it elsewhere!

Comment: Yes, on that exact append it failed but it will not error out if no duplicate is found. Did you test both types?

Comment: I'm happy that it won't error when no duplicate is found, but I don't want an error when a duplicate IS found, I just want to ignore it and not import that particular record.  The suggestion from Zev Spitz above does exactly what I need it to on this occasion.

Comment: You can add error handling to bypass that raised error. See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm). Regardless, I highly recommend parameterizing your query. Happy coding!